# Sort the rows based on sub group total in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have seen this link http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmanakumar/fDCcH/ which is very useful, i need to add one more feature like "Sort subgroups based on total".
In above example,i need to display subgroups in below order
Job2-24
and it's corresponding rows
Job3-21
and it's corresponding rows
Job1-11
and it's corresponding rows

Can some one help me in doing it done ??

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    });

    $(function() {
        var oTable = $('#job_history').dataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [4, 5, 6]}],
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], ["Show 10 entries", "Show 25 entries", "Show 50 entries", "Show all entries"]],
            "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "aaSortingFixed": [[5, 'asc']],
            "aaSorting": [[5, 'asc']],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sDom": '<flip>',
            "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
                if (oSettings.aiDisplay.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // GROUP ROWS
                var nTrs = $('#job_history tbody tr');
                var iColspan = nTrs[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length;
                var sLastGroup = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < nTrs.length; i++) {
                    var iDisplayIndex = oSettings._iDisplayStart + i;
                    var sGroup = oSettings.aoData[oSettings.aiDisplay[iDisplayIndex]]._aData[5];

                    if (sGroup != sLastGroup) {
                        var nGroup = document.createElement('tr');
                        var nCell = document.createElement('td');
                        nCell.colSpan = iColspan;
                        nCell.className = "group";
                        nCell.innerHTML = sGroup;
                        nGroup.appendChild(nCell);
                        nTrs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(nGroup, nTrs[i]);
                        sLastGroup = sGroup;
                    }
                }

                // SUM COLUMNS WITHIN GROUPS
                var total = 0;
                $("#job_history tbody tr").each(function(index) {
                    if ($(this).find('td:first.group').html()) {
                        total = 0;
                    } else {
                        total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(this.cells[4].innerHTML);
                        $(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr:has(td.group):first').find("div").html(total);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
```